# PHP references not working as I expect them to

Tags: php, oop, reference

Basically how I understand references work is

```
$a = 5;
$b = &$a;
$a = 10;
echo $b; // 10;
```

However in this bit of code I'm getting unexpected (for me, which probably has an explanation) result

```
class Room {
    
    private $users = array();
    
    public function addUser(&$user){
        $this->users[] = $user;
    }
}

$users = array(
    1 => 'Tom',
    2 => 'Hank',
    3 => 'Sam',
    4 => 'John'
);

$room = new Room();
$room->addUser($users[1]);
$room->addUser($users[3]);

unset($users[3]);

echo "<pre>" . print_r($room, true) . "</pre>";
echo "<pre>" . print_r($users, true) . "</pre>";
```

I expect, after unsetting `$users[3]`, the only user inside of `$room` to be `Tom`, but that is not the case, both `Tom` and `Sam` are present in the object. Why is `unset` not affecting the object's property?

## EDIT:

Even if I take things a step further with the example and create a class `User` the effect is still the same

```
class Room {
    
    private $users = array();
    
    public function addUser(&$user){
        $this->users[] = $user;
    }
}

class User {
    
    public $name;
    
    function __construct($name){
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

$users = array(
    1 => new User('Tom'),
    2 => new User('Hank'),
    3 => new User('Sam'),
    4 => new User('John')
);

$room = new Room();
$room->addUser($users[1]);
$room->addUser($users[3]);

unset($users[3]);

echo "<pre>" . print_r($room, true) . "</pre>";
echo "<pre>" . print_r($users, true) . "</pre>";
```

Comment: You are removing element from array, but not destroying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reference Counting Basics](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php) :

> A PHP variable is stored in a container called a "zval". A zval
>   container contains, besides the variable's type and value, two
>   additional bits of information. The first is called "is_ref" and is a
>   boolean value indicating whether or not the variable is part of a
>   "reference set". (...) Since PHP allows user-land references, as
>   created by the & operator, a zval container also has an internal
>   reference counting mechanism to optimize memory usage. This second
>   piece of additional information, called **"refcount", contains how many
>   variable names (also called symbols) point to this one zval container**.
>
> (...)
>
> **Variable containers get destroyed when the "refcount" reaches zero**. 
>   The **"refcount" gets decreased by one** when any symbol linked to the
>   variable container leaves the scope (e.g. when the function ends) or
>   **when unset() is called** on a symbol.

Example with arrays:

```
<?php
$a = array(
    0 => 'aaa',
    1 => 'bbb',
    2 => 'ccc',
);
debug_zval_dump($a); 
// ... string(3) "bbb" refcount(1) ...

$b = array();
$b[0] = &$a[0];
$b[1] = &$a[1];

$a[1] = 'ddd';
debug_zval_dump($a);
// ... &string(3) "bbb" refcount(2) ...
debug_zval_dump($b);
// ... &string(3) "bbb" refcount(2) ...

unset($a[1]);
debug_zval_dump($a);
/*
 array(2) refcount(2){
  [0]=>
  &string(3) "aaa" refcount(2)
  [1]=>
  &string(3) "ddd" refcount(2)
}
 */
debug_zval_dump($b);
// ... string(3) "ddd" refcount(1) ...

var_dump($a);
/*
array (size=2)
  0 => &string 'aaa' (length=3)
  2 => string 'ccc' (length=3)
*/
var_dump($b);
/*
 array (size=2)
  0 => &string 'aaa' (length=3)
  1 => string 'ddd' (length=3)
 */
```

Answer (score 4):

Unset operates on symbols, not reference targets.

That is why using unset on an undefined variable doesn't raise any kind of error.

```
$a = 10;
$b = &$a;
unset($b); // forget the name "$b" exists.
echo $a; // 10
```

If you want to unset it in both places, you have to assign `null` to one of the variables. This is a "hard unset", as opposed to a "soft unset" which is what you are currently doing.

Also you are not assigning a reference, you're assigning a copy.

```
$this->users[] = &$user;
```

Comment: I never heard about this "hard unset" and "soft unset" thing. They won't unset it in both places when null is assigned to one of the variables: the variable container still exists, but the value is null, because that's what was assigned. The variable container has a reference counter. It starts with the value 1 and it increases by one when it is referenced somewhere else. The "unset" decreases the reference counter by one and the variable container is destroyed when the counter reaches zero - that's why unset is "not affecting the object's property".

Comment: Things that are null are not set.

Comment: From the PHP manual [(Reference Counting Basics)](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php): "Variable containers get destroyed when the "refcount" reaches zero. **The "refcount" gets decreased by one** when any symbol linked to the variable container leaves the scope (e.g. when the function ends) or **when unset() is called** on a symbol."
Then how does reference counting work?

Comment: From the PHP manual [(isset)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) : "Determine if a variable **is set** and **is not NULL**." (...) "isset() will return FALSE if testing a variable that has been **set to NULL**"

You could say correctly that a NULL is not a value, but is set. I did not downvoted any answer.

Comment: Yes. Things that are null are not set. Like I said.

Comment: I think you are confusing existence with being set.

Comment: I answered OP btw: "Why is unset not affecting the object's property?"

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a slight logical problem between your desired effect and the way you try to do it.

If I understand correctly, you want to assign users to a container, then unsetting one of those user in a way that it will also be unsetted in your container. This

```
unset($users[3]);
```

unsets the value of the fourth element of your users array.

if we did `$user[3] = 'foo';` the value contained in the corresponding container's entry will be set to `'foo'` as well, but the container's index key itself will not get unset, or affected by the reference, **because it is not part of the referenced value**

If you want to unset the user, either you keep track of which index key is assigned to which user in your container and then delete users with this index key, or you set the value of `$users[3]` to `null` (or whatever suits your needs) and skip the `null` values when dealing with your container

Answer (score 0):

You can change a value of arrays, like this:

CODE:

```
    private $users = array();

    public function addUser(&$user){
        $this->users[] = &$user;
    }
}

$users = array(
    1 => 'Tom',
    2 => 'Hank',
    3 => 'Sam',
    4 => 'John'
);

$room = new Room();
$room->addUser($users[1]);
$room->addUser($users[3]);

$users[3] = "AAA123";


echo "<pre>" . print_r($room, true) . "</pre>";
echo "<pre>" . print_r($users, true) . "</pre>";
```

OUTPUT:

```
Room Object
(
    [users:Room:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Tom
            [1] => AAA123
        )

)

Array
(
    [1] => Tom
    [2] => Hank
    [3] => AAA123
    [4] => John
)
```

But delete it's not possible this way... I don't know how to explain, so just give example:

```
$a = 10;
$b = &$a;
unset($a);
echo $b; // 10
```

Then you deleting variable name, you not delete zval(container), until `refcount` reach 0... then "Garbage Collection" do all work and delete zval...

So method unset() remove variable name only in this case...

Answer (score -1):

Be careful.

You are passing to `addUser()` a reference to the string `'Tom'` allocated while building the array `$users`.

First, `addUser()` should read `$this->users[] =& $user;`, otherwise you will be copying the value into `$this->users[]` instead of sharing the reference.

Now, both `$users` and `Room::$users` share the same objects, however `unset($users[3])` **removes the element** mapped by the index `3` **from the array**, it does not destroy the mapped object.